# How to prove that if $A$ is algebra then $\mu(A)=\sigma(A)$?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-writing

Prove that if $A$ is algebra, then $\mu(A)=\sigma(A)\qquad$ $(\mu(A)\quad$is monotone class, generateg by A$)$.

Comment: What is $\mu$? What is $\sigma$?

Comment: One containment is trivial. Do you see which one? What are your thoughts about the other direction?

Comment: $\mu(A)\subset\sigma(A)$ it's  trivial, yes ?

Comment: Search for "monotone class theorem". Also you can take a look [here](https://www.cmi.ac.in/~prateek/measure_theory/2010-09-01.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction is easy. The other direction takes a bit more effort. Hint:

Set $\mathcal G = \{E \in \mathcal M(\mathcal A) |\, \forall F \in \mathcal M(\mathcal A): E\cap F, E\backslash F, F\backslash E \in \mathcal M(\mathcal A) \}$. Your first aim is to show that $\mathcal G$ is a monotone class. Have fun.

$\mathcal M(\mathcal A)$ is the monotone class generated by $\mathcal A$. Don't use $\mu$!!